# Pandas sum aggregation horizontally and vertically

Tags: python, pandas, math, sum, aggregation

Hi I have this for example

```
----------------------------------
| Item | Price | Qty | Price/Qty |
|---------------------------------
|  A   | 1     | 10  | 0.1       |
|  B   | 20    | 50  | 0.4       |
|  C   | 30    | 30  | 1         |
----------------------------------
```

When I do pivot group by item and sum price, qty and price/qty, sum(price/qty) is different from sum(price)/sum(qty). is there a way to have a column to calculate the value needed for me to get sum(price/qty) = sum(price)/sum(qty)?

ex. sum(price/qty) = 0.1 + 0.4 + 1 = 1.5 is different from sum(price) / sum(qty) = (1 + 20 + 30) / (10 + 50 + 30) = 0.567 which is right?

Comment: Please show us your existing code and a sample of your input, as well as desired output. In other words, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I meant if it is possible to have the values in column price/qty to sum equally as df["price"].sum()/df["qty"].sum() so I could just do df.groupby("item").sum() and get the right values - because i'm exporting as a dataset to be used as input to pivot elsewhere

Comment: This is not a python or a pandas question. it's a math question. What are you trying to achieve?